# Extract a String to array of CGPoints in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a string containing a list of thousands of geo coordinates

> "[8.2627925,46.3460497],[8.2612673,46.3457009],[8.2602494,46.3453934],..."

and would like to extract all of them in an array of CGPoints.
The code I am using today is the following:

```
let coords=[CGPoint]()
while substring.contains("[")
{
      index = substring.index(of: "[")!
      substring = substring[index...]
                                
      index = substring.index(of: "]")!
      let coordinate = substring[..<index]
      var indexComma = coordinate.index(of: ",")!
      let coordX = String(coordinate[..<indexComma])
      indexComma = coordinate.index(indexComma, offsetBy: +1)
      let coordY = String(coordinate[indexComma...])
      coords.append(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(Double(coordX)!), y: CGFloat(Double(coordY)!)))
      substring = substring[index...]
 }
```

However I am sure it can be optimised, possibly using regex. What would be the most efficient way ?

Comment: Seem almost like JSON, if you enclose it with "[""]. I'd decode it that way first.... Do you really need regex? Else: `let arrayOfPoints = try? JSONDecoder().decode([[Double]].self, from: Data(("[" + pointsStr + "]").utf8); let arrayOfCGPoints = arrayOfPoints.map { CGPoint(x: $0[0], y: $0[1]) }`

Comment: It doesn't look like but if this was valid GeoJSON you could parse it with [MKGeoJSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkgeojsondecoder)

Comment: 1. Remove all [ and ] instances at a time.  2. Get an array of components separated by the comma.  3. Loop through the array and save each element in coords.

Comment: Could someone help me to understand why the minus votes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the better efficient way is using to json serialization. Json can not serialize your string because its not in to correct format  so you can insert "[" and "]" for serialize it like below

```
 var coordinates = "[1.3123,3.2131],[2.3123,4.213]"
 coordinates.insert("[", at: coordinates.startIndex)
 coordinates.insert("]", at: coordinates.endIndex)
```

Now , our data is ready for serialization.Then the easiest part is appending poinst to `CGPoint` array

```
 var points : [CGPoint] = []
 if let data = coordinates.data(using: .utf8),
      let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[Double]] {
        points.append(contentsOf: jsonArray.map{CGPoint(x: $0[0], y: $0[1]) })
        print(points)

    }
```

You can easily reach ur datas

```
print(points[0].x) // 1.3123
print(points[1].y) // 4.213
```

Comment: `let data = Data(coordinates.utf8)` would avoid you a `if let` ;)